# Primefaces picklist appears empty if I add sessionscoped to the bean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean, session-scope, picklist

Primefaces Picklistbean has no scope defined, then primefaces picklist source and target lists are full but if I add sessionscoped to the Picklistbean then the source and target lists are empty. I would like to know why it appears empty when I add sessionscoped to Picklistbean

```
@ManagedBean(name="pickListBean")
public class PickListBean {

private DualListModel<TrvrTani> tanis;

private DualListModel<TrvrIlac> ilacs;

public DualListModel<TrvrIlac> getIlacs() {
    return ilacs;
}

public void setIlacs(DualListModel<TrvrIlac> ilacs) {
    this.ilacs = ilacs;
}

public DualListModel<TrvrTani> getTanis() {
    return tanis;
}

public void setTanis(DualListModel<TrvrTani> tanis) {
    this.tanis = tanis;
}

public PickListBean() {

    List<TrvrTani> sourcetani = new ArrayList<TrvrTani>();
    List<TrvrTani> targettani = new ArrayList<TrvrTani>();

    TrvrTaniDAO tanidao = new TrvrTaniDAO();
    List<TrvrTani> taniList = tanidao.findAll();
    for (TrvrTani tani : taniList) {
        sourcetani.add(new TrvrTani(tani.getTaniid(), tani.getTaniadi(),
                tani.getTanikodu()));
    }

    tanis = new DualListModel<TrvrTani>(sourcetani, targettani);

    List<TrvrIlac> sourceilac = new ArrayList<TrvrIlac>();
    List<TrvrIlac> targetilac = new ArrayList<TrvrIlac>();

    TrvrIlacDAO ilacdao = new TrvrIlacDAO();
    List<TrvrIlac> ilacList = ilacdao.findAll();
    for (TrvrIlac ilac : ilacList) {
        sourceilac.add(new TrvrIlac(ilac.getIlacid(), ilac.getIlacad(),
                ilac.getBarkod(), null));
    }

    ilacs = new DualListModel<TrvrIlac>(sourceilac, targetilac);

}

public void onTransferTani(TransferEvent event) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object item : event.getItems()) {
        builder.append(((TrvrTani) item).getTaniadi()).append("<br />");
    }

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();
    msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
    msg.setSummary("Items Transferred");
    msg.setDetail(builder.toString());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public void onTransferIlac(TransferEvent event) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object item : event.getItems()) {
        builder.append(((TrvrIlac) item).getIlacad()).append("<br />");
    }

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();
    msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
    msg.setSummary("Items Transferred");
    msg.setDetail(builder.toString());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
}
```

xhtml

```
            <h:outputText value="Tanı: " />
                <p:pickList id="picklist" value="#{pickListBean.tanis}" size="60"
                    cols="60" var="tani" converter="acconverter"
                    itemValue="#{tani}" itemLabel="#{tani.taniadi}"
                    showSourceControls="false" showTargetControls="false"
                    showCheckbox="false" showSourceFilter="true"
                    showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">

                    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Tanılar</f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Eklenen tanılar</f:facet>

                    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{pickListBean.onTransferTani}" />


                    <p:column style="width:75%;">  
                            #{tani.taniadi}  
                    </p:column>

                </p:pickList>
                <br />
                <p:message for="picklist" />

                <h:outputText value="İlaç: " />
                <p:pickList id="picklist2" value="#{pickListBean.ilacs}" size="60"
                    cols="60" var="ilac" converter="acconverterilac"
                    itemValue="#{ilac}" itemLabel="#{ilac.ilacad}"
                    showSourceControls="false" showTargetControls="false"
                    showCheckbox="false" showSourceFilter="true"
                    showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">

                    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">İlaçlar</f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Eklenen ilaçlar</f:facet>

                    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{pickListBean.onTransferIlac}" />


                    <p:column style="width:75%;">  
                            #{ilac.ilacad}  
                    </p:column>

                </p:pickList>
                <br />
                <p:message for="picklist2" />
```

Comment: could you please put your xhtml page

Comment: Why are you choosing the `@SessionScoped`? Try the `@ViewScoped` instead

Comment: If I import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped for ViewScoped then the picklist is full

Comment: but again if I import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped It's empty

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
```

in place of `@ManagedBean(name="pickListBean")`

at the top

Comment: I did what you write first I didn't remove ManagedBean(name="pickListBean") and put Named and SessionScoped then again it was empty then I removed ManagedBean(name="pickListBean") and put Named and SessionScoped but then it says target unreachable

Comment: Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /yenimuayene.xhtml @87,58 value="#{pickListBean.tanis}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'pickListBean' resolved to null

Comment: My problem is if I add sessionscoped to the bean, then the picklist appears empty, when I remove sessionscoped from the bean, picklist is full